# Flash Projector with multiple windows, each with a new flashPlayer instance

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

Does anyone know of a flash projector 'project' or 'framework' that uses a new flashPlayer for each window?

We've used mProjector, which works well to a point, but I'm very disappointed in the fileIO patterns they use.  It is very buggy with regard to reading and writing files.

mdm zinc uses multiple windows, but it is all sits on one flashPlayer 'session'.  The same applies for AIR.  It is great, but there isn't a way to make each window run on a seperate flashPlayer... extreme number crunching on one window will lock up all other windows.

Thank you in advance.  --jeremy

*edit* - Just to clarify my needs (since I'm adding a little bounty), the app is an ERP application, built on Flex 3.x, and the size and scope of the project == huge.

**tl;dr** -- I need an exe wrapper (for windows), similar to AIR, that can have multiple windows, running each window on a seperate flashPlayer instance, and when a window is closed, it blows-away that flashPlayer instance / stage / etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a DotNet application to handle the wrapper? It can spawn windows each with it's own instance of the Flash Player (ActiveX dll) running in it.

Comment: 'tis a good suggestion.  However there are a lot of tools built into 'frameworks' like AIR, mdm Zinc, and mProjector that would be needed, and my hope is that a project exists that already has these tools.  Downloading files to the filesystem, for example; or quickly and easily managing an 'icon' in the sysTray.

If no such project exists, I'll give you the 50+ for what seems to be the only answer.  I'm just lazy!!!

Comment: alright mr ireland... it's yours.  'Tisn't a suggestion we have time to implement, but at this point it does seem like one of the only options -- well, at least one of the better options for me, since I have a relatively firm handle on c# and have to support a pretty large c# sln on a semi-regular basis.   Thanks again.

Comment: A Scotsman working in Ireland if you will ;) And yeah, it isn't exactly a quick solution to implement, but you've certainly got requirements outside of the norm!

Answer (score 1):

I'm Sorry I found this too late to help you, but hopefully this saves someone else some work.

You can use SWF Studio to do this.

What you do is create a stub EXE that takes command line parameters to tell it which SWF to load. The parameter tells the EXE which SWF to load from its internal collection of files added to the SWF studio Files Tab. Whenever you need to open a new "window" you just execute your own EXE again and pass it the name of the SWF to use.

SWF Studio's App.sendData commands allows you to send data between youe various windows with very little effort so your separate applications can easily behave like they are all parts of a single application.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  The one part of our architecture that feels a bit too coupled is our 'shell'.  It wouldn't take too much work to un-wire the current projector platform, but it is time I don't currently have.  Plugging our modules into a shell built on swf studio would be quick and easy though... our library 'stack' is pretty smooth.  northcode -- I've seen that site before... how long have you guys been doing your thing?  Tell you what... I'll email you.

Comment: I wrote version 1 of SWF Studio in 2000 and it's been under the Northcode banner since 2002. We've been doing this for a bit :)